# Python Distutils: How to overwrite an existing module in another installed package

Tags: python, distutils

Im struggling on figuring out how to create a setup.py module that will overwrite a series of specific modules in another location.

For example, lets say I've got new_file_1.py and new_file_2.py (in the right directory structure above setpu.py)

```
/setup.py
/my_modules/__init__.py
/my_modules/new_file_file_1.py
/my_modules/new_file_file_2.py
```

and I need the new_files to overwrite old files that live in a path somewhere else, that is NOT one of the generic python library paths.

I realize its brute force, but is there a way to hard-code, or take in via command line, an absolute path that isn't going to to staple on all sorts of generic path stuff? e.g. if I tell setup.py --prefix=/some/path/ it will then install to /some/path/.../python2x/dist-packages/ or something like that.

I recognize a shell-script would be simpler, but the work I am doing at the moment necessitates everything stay within python scripts.

tldr, can I force distutils to simply put the files in a particular specified location?